# Cannot convert value of type 'MobileNetV2' to expected argument type 'VNCoreMLModel'

Tags: swift, xcode, computer-vision, arkit, coreml

I'm currently building a new app and trying to integrate a Core ML model with Vision to my app... unfortunately, Xcode shows me this message: Cannot convert value of type 'MobileNetV2' to expected argument type 'VNCoreMLModel'

How may I solve this?

Here's my code below:

```
let config = MLModelConfiguration()
    guard let coreMLModel = try? MobileNetV2(configuration: config),
          let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: coreMLModel.model) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't load model!")
    }
    
    
    let classificationRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: coreMLModel, completionHandler: classificationCompleteHandler)
    classificationRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop
    visionRequests = [classificationRequest]
    
    loopCoreMLUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line shouldn't use `coreMLModel` but `visionModel`:

```swift
let classificationRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: coreMLModel, completionHandler: classificationCompleteHandler)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what I wrote is correct. You should pass a VNCoreMLModel instance into VNCoreMLRequest but what you're passing in is a MobileNetV2 instance. This is literally what the Xcode error message says.

Comment: My bad... it finally worked! Thanks a lot for your help!